# Adding a Group ID to a query where the sort by is not based on the Column your grouping by

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add a groupID column to a query where the column the grouping is based on is sorted randomly

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
  ID INT primary key IDENTITY(1,1),
  ProductID INT,
  QuestionID INT
)


INSERT INTO @t (ProductID,QuestionID) 
SELECT  ProductID       
        ,QuestionID    
FROM    dbo.Products p WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN    dbo.Questions q  WITH(NOLOCK) on p.StudyID = q.StudyID
WHERE   p.StudyID = @StudyID
ORDER BY FIRST_VALUE(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY ProductID),
        ProductID,  
        QuestionNumber

SELECT ID,ProductID,QuestionID       
       , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ProductID) as ProductGroupID   
FROM   @t t  
ORDER BY ID
```

Every time the query is run there is a random sort off the ProductID Column.
I trying to get the GroupID to be 1,2,3 etc...  no matter what ProductID is first.

This is my goal
Example:

```
     ID  | ProductID   | GroupID   |  QuestionID
    -----|-------------|-----------|-------------
     1       22             1              2
     2       22             1              3
     3       22             1              5
     4       11             2              2
     5       11             2              3
     6       11             2              5
     7       44             3              2
     8       44             3              3
     9       44             3              5
```

If you re-query it should be:

```
     ID  | ProductID   | GroupID   |  QuestionID
     ----|-------------|-----------|-------------
     1       44             1              2
     2       44             1              3
     3       44             1              5
     4       11             2              2
     5       11             2              3
     6       11             2              5
     7       22             3              2
     8       22             3              3
     9       22             3              5
```

and again:

```
     ID  | ProductID   | GroupID   |  QuestionID
    -----|-------------|-----------|-------------
     1       11             1              2
     2       11             1              3
     3       11             1              5
     4       44             2              2
     5       44             2              3
     6       44             2              5
     7       22             3              2
     8       22             3              3
     9       22             3              5
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in my opinion would be to just add the randomly ordered sequential integer in the `SELECT` from `Product` before the join.

```
WITH Prod
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER()
                  OVER (ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) AS ProductGroupID
         FROM   dbo.Products
         WHERE  StudyID = @StudyID
         )
SELECT ProductID,
       QuestionID,
       ProductGroupID
FROM   Prod p
       JOIN dbo.Questions q
         ON p.StudyID = q.StudyID
ORDER  BY ProductGroupID,
          QuestionNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

As [sp_BlitzErik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/sp-blitzerik) has pointed out in comments you can use NTILE to 'distribute' your result set.

**[NTILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

> Distributes the rows in an ordered partition into a specified number of groups. The groups are numbered, starting at one. For each row, NTILE returns the number of the group to which the row belongs.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
  ProductID INT,
  QuestionID INT
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(22, 2),
(22, 3),
(22, 5),
(11, 2),
(11, 3),
(11, 5),
(44, 2),
(44, 3),
(44, 5);


;WITH CT AS
(
SELECT 
    ProductID,
    FIRST_VALUE(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY ProductID) RndOrder
FROM
    @t
GROUP BY 
    ProductID
)
SELECT
    t.ProductID,
    t.QuestionID,
    NTILE((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT QuestionID) FROM @t)) OVER (ORDER BY RndOrder) GroupID
FROM
    @t t
JOIN
    CT ON CT.ProductID = t.ProductID
ORDER BY
    RndOrder;
```

This solution assumes that all products have the same number of questions. The number of groups used by NTILE is set to 3 in this case.

```
ProductID | QuestionID | GroupID
--------: | ---------: | :------
       11 |          2 | 1      
       11 |          3 | 1      
       11 |          5 | 1      
       44 |          2 | 2      
       44 |          3 | 2      
       44 |          5 | 2      
       22 |          2 | 3      
       22 |          3 | 3      
       22 |          5 | 3
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=79a82bb4fcd012712e49bbde5f68005a)*

Answer (score 0):

Hope I have understood your requirement correctly .

```
 declare @t table(ID int,ProductID int,GroupID int,QuestionID int)
insert INTO @t VALUES
( 1  , 22,1,2)
,( 2  , 22,1,3)
,( 3  , 22,1,5)
,( 4  , 11,2,2)
,( 5  , 11,2,3)
,( 6  , 11,2,5)
,( 7  , 44,3,2)
,( 8  , 44,3,3)
,( 9  , 44,3,5)

--select * from @t
;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT TOP 5000 ID
        ,ProductID AS ProductID
        ,QuestionID
    FROM @t
    ORDER BY FIRST_VALUE(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) OVER (
            PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY ProductID
            )
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY (
                    SELECT NULL
                    )
            ) rn
    FROM cte
    )
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM cte1;

WITH CTE4
AS (
    SELECT productid
        ,min(rn) AS rn2
    FROM #temp
    GROUP BY productid
    )
SELECT t.id
    ,t.productid
    ,t.questionid
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY c4.rn2
        ) AS Groupid
FROM #temp t
INNER JOIN CTE4 c4 ON t.productid = c4.productid

DROP TABLE #temp
```

@t is  output from your own query. So you can store your query in Temp table or CTE not table variable.

Or you can say how much rows will be return from your own query ?

My logic start from **CTE1** and not CTE.

What is real life scenario like ?

May be Group ID should be assign in UI,but it depend upon other thing.